Challenges around using relative imports in python
I have the following project hierarchy:
project/
├── data/
├── images/
├── src/
│   ├── dir1/
│   │   ├── data_processing/
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── import_data.py  
│   │   ├── model_dev/
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── gpt_int.py
│   │   └── model_eval/

I would now like to call a module named "load_data" from the import_data.py code into the gpt_int.py code that is stored within the model_dev directory.
I have already tried every possible solution such as
from src.dir1.data_processing.import_data import load_data

but this is not working. I have tried relative paths as well using
from ..dir1.data_processing... this is not working as well. I am getting an error that "No Module named src"
Any possible resolution around this problem?

add project folder complete path to your PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Sometimes, we tend to forget to create an __init__.py file in all the folders we have in our project.  Without it, Python won't recognize the folder as a package, and thus you can't import any module or objects (function, classes etc.) from it. So, ensure to that to all your folders, and I am certain it is likely going to work. And one more thing, make sure you don't name any module or folder the same name with a package/library you previously installed to avoid conflict, we tend to forget that one too.
In your root directory, src of your project folder tree, ensure to put init file there like I stated above.

It's still not working. I have added the init.py file at the src folder as well but when I am making the import calls, the error says No module named 'src'

the dir1 has no init.py file as well based on your project structure. Please try and add it, also. Upgrade your pip too.
